# FontAwesome Icon not showing for button

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

```
<ng-template pTemplate="summary" let-rowData>
<div style="text-align:left">
  <i class="fa fa-pencil" title="Edit"></i>
  <button type="button" pButton icon="fa fa-pencil" (click)="showDialogToAdd()" label="Add"></button>
</div>
```

The pencil icon will show but the button will not.  However, the button will not.

[image: example]

This is ripped from the primeng example

https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/showcase/components/table/tablepagedemo.html

(I added the pencil icon just for proof it's not an issue with the css I am attempting to include)

Why is this happening?

Comment: The button is likely using the wrong font.  Inspect it in your dev tools and you'll see it has a different font than the `i` element above it.

Comment: I'm looking at the file that you linked and I don't see any `<button>` examples there to draw from.

Comment: Found the issue, forgot to include pButton in my app module, thanks!

Comment: @jayjay93 PrimeNG now recommends using Prime Icons. Hope this link helps https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-6-0-0-beta-1-released-primeicons/

Answer (score 1):

Define the font-awesome icon in a `class` attribute on your button, instead of a `icon` attribute.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div style="text-align:left">
  <i class="fa fa-pencil-alt" title="Edit"></i>
  <button type="button" pButton class="fa fa-pencil-alt" ></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Found the issue, forgot to include pButton in my app module